# 6 commits 0 files changed github

Tags: git, github

I have 2 branches ... Production and Staging and they are very identical ... i always make the `Squash and Merge` Option to merge commits from Staging for example 4 commits ... squashed them to production into 1 commit and merge using Github ... but i don't know how to solve this ... every time i make a new PR from `staging to production` it shows

n commits with no file changes ... while the opposite (`Production to Staging`) shows this message (`There isn't anything to compare`)

How can i get rid of those commits with 0 files changes ... all i do is fetch and rebase staging from production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Squash and Merge` option creates a new commit on the target branch, which changes its history. This is why you'll always see the `there isn't anything to compare` or `<n> commits with no file changes` messages when comparing two otherwise identical branches.

If possible, I'd suggest using the regular `Merge` action over `Squash and Merge` when merging Pull Requests, as that will keep the history of the two branches identical and prevent this issue going forward.

Comment: Yes using the regular merge solve the problem ... thanks @Adil B